# Retrieve REL contents from variable number of elements and store in array

Tags: jquery, arrays, area, rel

I've been trying to work out how to do this but there's just too many moving parts for my level of jQuery/JavaScript so I can't work out where I'm going wrong.

I'm simply trying to create an array from all REL attributes in a variable number of **area** tags:

```
<map name="Map">
    <area shape="rect" coords="45,13,125,107" class="lightbox" rel="/img/yachts/layouts/sml/horizon-56-aft-stateroom.jpg" href="/img/yachts/layouts/lrg/horizon-56-aft-stateroom.JPG" alt="Aft Stateroom" title="Aft Stateroom">
    <area shape="rect" coords="310,37,366,83" class="lightbox" rel="/img/yachts/layouts/sml/horizon-56-vip-cabin-2.JPG" href="/img/yachts/layouts/lrg/horizon-56-vip-cabin-2.JPG" alt="VIP Cabin" title="VIP Cabin">
    <area shape="rect" coords="126,19,207,99" class="lightbox" rel="/img/yachts/layouts/sml/horizon-56-salon.jpg" href="/img/yachts/layouts/lrg/horizon-56-salon.jpg" alt="Saloon" title="Saloon">
    <area shape="rect" coords="207,12,284,52" class="lightbox" rel="/img/yachts/layouts/sml/horizon-56-port-cabin.jpg" href="/img/yachts/layouts/lrg/horizon-56-port-cabin.jpg" alt="VIP Cabin" title="Port Cabin">
    <area shape="rect" coords="223,68,285,116" class="lightbox" rel="/img/yachts/layouts/sml/horizon-56-starbord-cabin.jpg" href="/img/yachts/layouts/lrg/horizon-56-starbord-cabin.jpg" alt="VIP Cabin" title="Starboard Cabin">
    <area shape="rect" coords="4,16,37,107" class="lightbox" rel="/img/yachts/layouts/sml/horizon-56-platform.jpg" href="/img/yachts/layouts/lrg/horizon-56-platform.jpg" alt="VIP Cabin" title="Swim Platform">
    <area shape="rect" coords="366,28,406,96"  class="lightbox" rel="/img/yachts/layouts/sml/Horizon-56-bowpad.jpg" href="/img/yachts/layouts/lrg/horizon-56-bowpad.JPG" alt="Bow" title="Bow of Horizon 56">
  </map>
```

My end goal is to feed this to a simple jQuery preloader to preload these images but I can handle that bit once I can get the array built!

Thanks in advance for any and all help!

Bob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CFGb7/1/

```
// create array for storing rels
var rels = [];
// loop through each `area` element
// you could adjust this selector to be more specific if you like
$('area').each(function(i, el){
    // push onto the array, each element's `rel` attribute
    rels.push($(el).attr('rel'));
})
// check what the array looks like now :)
console.log(rels)
// should log to console...
// ["/img/yachts/layouts/sml/horizon-56-aft-stateroom.jpg", "/img/yachts/layouts/sml/horizon-56-vip-cabin-2.JPG", "/img/yachts/layouts/sml/horizon-56-salon.jpg", "/img/yachts/layouts/sml/horizon-56-port-cabin.jpg", "/img/yachts/layouts/sml/horizon-56-starbord-cabin.jpg", "/img/yachts/layouts/sml/horizon-56-platform.jpg", "/img/yachts/layouts/sml/Horizon-56-bowpad.jpg"]
```

Comment: My pleasure - jQuery is a wonderful tool, as is stack overflow. I don't know where I would be without either of them :)